# Connecting to Google Cloud SQL from WaveMaker Online

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-cloud-sql, wavemaker

Has anyone had any success connecting to Google Cloud SQL from Wavemaker Online? I've had it confirmed through the chat that this is possible but the documentation linked didn't mention it directly.

When I try to test connection I get the error message:

> Error in connecting to database. : "Connection timed out",please check
>   server logs for more information

To connect I have done the following:

- Import > Connect to Database
- Select an external database > Other
- Import Driver > mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar
- Database Info:

  - User Name: root
  - Password: {root password}
  - Database Name: {database name}
  - Schema Filter: {left blank}
- Advanced Settings:

  - Service Name: CloudSql
  - Port: 3306
  - Connection URL: jdbc:mysql://{IPv4 address}
  - Java Package: {Default}
  - Driver Class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  - Dialect: MySql

Is there something I need to do on the Cloud SQL end? Are there some specific IP addresses to add to the Authorised Networks maybe? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide the ip from wavemakeronline(wich we dont know) to google cloud for authorize the access or connection.. so is bit complicated that wm support can send to you the ip

Comment: They will give you the IP. I have it with me. But I'm not sure If I can share it here.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can add 0.0.0.0/0 as IP, it will allow ANY IP to connect your database.